# Missing number in the table

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

This is my 3x3 grid:

$$\begin{matrix} 2 & 6 & 8 \\ 3 & 7 & 3 \\ 6 & 4 & x \end{matrix}$$

Here x should be replaced with some number. Based on the solutions it should be x=1. Can anyone explain the logic?

Comment: it seems like that this puzzle comes from elsewhere. please provide the source. unattributed work may get downvoted or even closed. happy puzzling ;)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> 1

because

> 2 6 8
>  plus
>  3 7 3
>  is exactly
>  6 4 1 (not sure yet)